# selecting columns which are NOT of a specific type SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to select all the columns in BigQuery that are not of the type "TIMESTAMP". I have written the query which returns such columns which is:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM d1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
     TABLE_NAME   = 't1' AND
     DATA_TYPE != 'TIMESTAMP'
```

But I am struggling to return data from only these columns in SQL, I have tried the following query which results in "Scalar subquery produced more than one element".

```
SELECT (
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM d1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
     TABLE_NAME   = 't1' AND
     DATA_TYPE != 'TIMESTAMP'
) from `d1.t1`;
```

Can anyone please help me out here in getting the columns from table 't1' where the datatype!=TIMESTAMP? Thanking you in anticipation!

Comment: use `execute immediate`

Comment: Thanks for responding. 

I tried:

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
"SELECT ( SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM d1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME   = 't1' AND DATA_TYPE != 'TIMESTAMP') from `d1.t1`";

but am still getting the same error i.e. "Scalar subquery produced more than one element".

Comment: i did not mean just adding `execute immediate` - i meant - **use it**. see multiple examples here on SO of using it! hint: you will also need to use `string_agg` function to transform all those columns into list of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying @Mikhail's advise in the comment's section, you can try this query:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE col_not_tmstmp STRING;
-- putting the result of your query into a variable
SET  col_not_tmstmp = (SELECT STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM <your-project>.<your-dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
     TABLE_NAME   = '<your_table>' AND
     DATA_TYPE != 'TIMESTAMP');

-- use execute immediate to apply the variable to main query
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT (""" 
SELECT %s 
FROM  `<your-project>.<your-dataset>.<your_table>` 
""", col_not_tmstmp
);
END
```

Table:
[image]

Output:
[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you! this does say that the query has executed fine but I am not getting a normal response which I usually get from "select * from ABC". Can you please tell me what to do next in order to get that response?

Comment: Can you please specify what "normal response" are you referring to?

Comment: I don't get the rows rather I have to click on the query to see the actual response.

Comment: Since we used [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) in our script, it will return the result of each statement, hence we cannot check the query directly.

Comment: ahh ok, thanks for the clarification! Is there any way I can use it in the "create model" statement in BQ? I tried the traditional way of adding it instead of "select * from table" and it's not working.

Comment: For that question since it is unrelated to your original post, you can post a different question here in StackOverflow so that the community can easily find the answer.